# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest not updating UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking

I am downloading an image from a URL using `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure` and the download of the image works correctly. The issue I am having is that when I set the downloaded image to the `UIIMageView` nothing shows but the placeholder is removed.

My code is as follows:

```
__weak UIImageView *userCardImageView;


AFImageResponseSerializer *serializer = [[AFImageResponseSerializer alloc] init];
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [serializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/png"];
self.userCardImageView.imageResponseSerializer = serializer;

[self.userCardImageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

        [userCardImageView setImage:image];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error:   %@", error);
            NSLog(@"Error response:     %@", response);
        }

    }];
```

The URL is correct as when I copy and past it into a browser I get my image.

Can someone advise me how I can get my code to work to update the URL? Am I right to assign the `UIImageView` to a weak property? I am doing this as using self or a strong variable could lead to a retain cycle.

Comment: This method  automatically sets image. Remove `[userCardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:userCardImageData]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you should implement the line

```
[userCardImageView setImage:image];
```

instead of

```
[userCardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:userCardImageData]];
```

in your success block

PS: If it is the self.userCardImageView which you want to set the image in, you would rather declare a weak controller instead of a weak UIImageView reference. Something like

```
__weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self
```

Comment: Thanks for answering James, I had been using `[userCardImageView setImage:image];` in my code but while editing I had removed the wrong line. I tried using the weak controller you suggested and that worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not assigning the downloaded image to image view correctly.`[userCardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:userCardImageData]];`, we need not to assign the image from this variable `userCardImageData`, try this code

```
[self.userCardImageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [userCardImageView setImage:image]; //set image in main thread , we got downloaded image as parameter in block
    });


} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error:   %@", error);
        NSLog(@"Error response:     %@", response);
    }

}];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering Saif, this didn't work unfortunately however James' suggestion of using weakSelf did.

Answer (score 0):

Should be enough just:

```
[self.userCardImageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion orkenstein, I was using this originally and it worked but I needed a bit more control over the download so had to use the blocks